# VBA Conditional Statement with Target.Cells.CountLarge Not Working

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, target

Desired Behaviour:

I want to change the value of a cell if and only if a cell current value of another cell matches some constant string value (only alpha characters) I have chosen.

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    With ActiveWindow

        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        Dim selection As Long
        selection = Target.Cells.CountLarge
        Dim someString As String
        someString= "something"



        If selection = 1 Then
            If (Target.Column = 4 And Target.Value = someString And IsEmpty(Target) =False) Then
                thisrow = Target.Row
                sht.Cells(thisrow, 5).Value = "N/A"
            End If
        End If


    End With
End Sub
```

Question:
Is there a better way to handle this?  The first if statement is necessary to ensure one cell is selected and to avoid error message type mismatch.

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to use the Selection Change event? I.e. the cell in column 5 will be "N/A" only if you _select_ a "something" cell in column 4?

Comment: One note `IsEmpty(Target) =False` is kind of redundant.  If it equals `somestring` it can't be empty and if it is empty it will not equal that string.

Comment: Other question: Is "Sheet1" the same sheet as where the SelectionChange Event is? If yes then there is no need to assgin sht to "Sheet1". And what is ActiveWindow good for?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick rewrite that does the same thing, but without some of the superfluous stuff:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'First test to make sure this is a cell we care about 
    '  (before declaring variables and gathering any other info)
    If Target.Column = 4 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then        
        'Now we know we have a single cell selected in column D

        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        Dim someString As String
        someString= "something"

        If Target.Value = someString Then           
            sht.Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = "N/A"
        End If    
End Sub
```

1. Removed the `With` as it wasn't being used (and I can't imagine what `activewindow` is useful for anyway in an event triggered subroutine like this
2. Moved all of the logic inside an `If` statement that first checks if we care about the selection change at all. This insures that we only run logic and tie up system resources if this is something we care about.
3. Removed superfluous `thisrow` variable as it was only being used once Although maybe you have more logic here that isn't being showed.
4. Removed superfluous check for `IsEmpty(Target) = False` which, while still superfluous, could be written also as `Not IsEmpty(Target)` as we are already dealing with a boolean return from the `Isempty` function.

Overall the logic to test if we care is separated nicely from the logic that does the all the work, which makes it more readable and reduces resources used.

---

Rewrite with the smallest foot print (again I'm assuming you have more code and the variables are necessary to reduce copy/paste code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Value = "something" Then          
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = "N/A"
        End If    
    End If
End Sub
```